# Can't include iostream in C using MS Visual C++?

Tags: c, struct, iostream, strcpy

I've been trying to learn C, and I'm stuck on including libraries. I need to use strcpy(), but that method is included in the iostream library, but whenever I try to include the library, the program gives me errors. I've tried using "iostream", "iostream.h", , , but it either gives me a "can't find iostream.h" error, or the program exceeds 100 errors and just crashes. Even if my code is empty, I still get the same thing. Here's the code:

```
#include "iostream"

int main(void)
{
}
```

Yup, just that much makes it crash already. And here's a part of the errors I'm getting (could never paste them all here):

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'abs'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(37): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'acos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'asin'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(39): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'atan2'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'ceil'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(40): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(41): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'cos'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\cmath(41): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So yeah it even exceeds the 100 errors and the program just stops counting. I don't understand why, I'm just including a regular library. Is there an equivalent of strcpy()? I mainly wanted to use it like this (for practice):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"

int main(void)
{
    struct person 
    { 
        int id; 
        char name[50];
        int age;
    }; 

    struct person p1;

    p1.id = 5595; 
    strcpy(p1.name, "Myname");
    p1.age = 18;

    printf("%d%s%d", p1.id, p1.name, p1.age);
}
```

Comment: note there's a difference between crashing and reporting errors :] ususally compilers report errors, seldom they crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<iostream>` is a C++ header (it deals with input/ouput streams, as the name implies).  If you want `strcpy`, you need `<string.h>`.

Comment: @user1007059 - please mark Oli Charlesworth's post "solved" ;)

Comment: @paulsm4, was trying to, but it kept telling me to wait 10 minutes ^^ but now I did :D

Answer (score 1):

If your source file is ".c", all you have to do is to rename it ".cpp".

Then it'll compile as C++, you'll have the C++ headers, and you'll be able to use C++ streams.

I don't see any need for iostreams, however.

Strcpy and friends are in "`<string.h>`".  Just include it, and "stdio.h" (like you're doing); delete the "iostreams" #include ... and life should be good.

Answer (score 0):

`iostream`s are a C++-only feature. The `iostream`s header file is written in C++, not C. (Yes, they are different languages!) Presumably, you're invoking the compiler in C mode, so when the compiler looks at the header file it of course throws lots of errors since many of the constructs used in `iostream` makes sense only in C++ mode.

If you want to use `iostream`s, you have to compile in C++ mode (and code in proper, modern C++ accordingly), use a different library that's C-only or work around it by implementing your own code as necessary.

In this case, all you apparently want to do is to use `strcpy()`. That is declared in the `string.h`, not `iostream`. (`string.h` is a C header file.) Just `#include <string.h>` and it should compile.